# Reading pins from MCP23017 using i2c

Tags: python, i2c

I am using the MCP23017 with my raspberry pi.. Now I wanted to try and program it.. But I am new at the i2c stuff so was wondering if what I am doing is right or not... I am confused regarding the read/write bit mentioned in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf)

I have connected my A0 pin to Vcc and A1,A2 pins to ground.. So I guess my address would be 0x21.. I have enabled the IOCON.MIRROR bit to '1' so that both INTA/B are set if either port A or port B input changes...
Now I wanted to clear a interrupt which may occur by reading the INTCAP/Gpio pins .
So is the following command right to do this -

```
subprocess.call('i2cget', '-y', '0', '0x21', '0x12')
```

I have a feeling that it is not right...
Could someone please advice me regarding this..

Thank you in advance,
Kind Regards,
Namita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the levels you applied to A0, A1 and A2, the address of the device is indeed 0x21.  Let me explain...
The read/write bit is simply the last bit of 8 bits, which make the complete address byte for a certain device.  Taking your MCP device, you always have to provide the first 7 bits of the address and looking to the datasheet, you will see the address can be anything between 0x20 (hex:0010.0000) and 0x27 (hex: 0010.0111).  Next to that, one extra bit is needed to specify the direction: read (1) or write (0).
This extra bit is implicitly added by the command i2cget (= read, so 1 will be added) or the command i2cset (= write, so 0 will be added).
So, in the end, the complete i2c address of the MCP23017 with initial address 0x20 will be 0x0100.0000 when you write to it (initial address is shifted one bit position to the left and the write bit, being 0, will be added to the right) and will be 0x0100.0001 when you read from it (same principle as for writing).
That said, your next question: after a reset of the device, all pins are set as inputs, so that's fine if you want to read something from the pins of the device.  Next, after a reset, the bank bit is also 0, meaning the registers to manipulate port A and port B are residing next to each other.  Which is also OK in your case.  Finally, you're reading register 0x12, which is GPIOA. Also fine.  The only thing that could prevent you from reading out something, is the I2C bus number, since you didn't specify which Raspberry Pi you're using.  Older RPi's use bus 0, newer RPi's use bus 1.
Other things you have to check: did you set the register that causes the interrupt to be generated, correctly?  If so, whenever something changes on input pins, the INTA/B pins will assert, until you read the content of the pin or its corresponding INT register content.  For the rest, I don't see anything wrong to the setup of your command (not the python part, but the string composed).
Did you try the bare i2cget command on the command line directly to see if that works fine?  Yet another test you can do...